# How to get C char * string value in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, unsafe-pointers

```
char*   iperf_get_test_json_output_string ( struct iperf_test* ipt );    // .h file
```

I am using iperf SDK .c file in iOS project in swift. Above function return (`char *`) pointer reference. I am getting pointer reference. Anyone Can help to get the string in swift using this above function?

```
var result =  iperf_get_test_json_output_string(test)
let temp = withUnsafePointer(to: result) {
          $0.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: $0) ) {
               String(cString: $0)
           }
```

Comment: Is `result` null terminated? If so, you can simply do `temp = String(cString: result)`

Comment: Thank you very much  @Ranoiaetep. temp = String(cString: result) is working.